# django authenticate user and generate JWT token

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, token

I wanna authenticate user to get JWT token which later I will pass to JS. 
But I'm getting the error saying:
**django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'AnonymousUser' is not a valid UUID."]**

My login functions:

**views.py**

```
def loginTest(request):
    user = authenticate(
        username=request.POST.get('username'),
        password=request.POST.get('password'))

    token, _ = Token.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

    return Response({'token': token.key},
                    status=HTTP_200_OK)
```

**urls.py**

```
from .views import loginTest

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/auth', loginTest),
]
```

**App.vue**

```
mounted() {
const url = window.location.origin
const data = {
    username: 'username',
    password: '123
}
    axios.post(url+'/accounts/api/auth', data)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response) 
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
}
```

the error which I'm getting is:
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

and have no idea why I like that

Comment: Do you have any user in the user model?

Comment: Yes I have, I have login view in django templates which is working but I wanna change the way of authentication thats why I wanna pass it to API

Comment: if i change for: Token.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user) -> Im' getting: 
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'AnonymousUser' is not a valid UUID."]

Comment: better go through the DRF and Axios documentation once. I noticed several issues with axios and DRF code.

Comment: You're passing the request from front end? I could see that in axios you're using post request and passing the the username and password as params which you should not. In axios you've to pass the post data in data object. and also in DRF side you're accessing it as a get method. Which you should not do. Instead, you've to access it as request.data. Also you shouldn't use request.GET.get instead you've to use request.query_params.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params

Comment: @ Aashay Amballi I updated my question but still I'm getting:
django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'AnonymousUser' is not a valid UUID."]

Comment: You're using Django or Django Rest Framework?

Comment: django rest framework

Comment: That's an actual view? loginTest? Did you check you're able to receive username and password? and also where is the @api_view decorator in your view. Also to get the post data you should use request.data instead of request.POST.get 
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data

Comment: I thought that maybe i need to add in urls:
    path('api/auth', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework'), loginTest),

im gettinf 200 but this time it retun html that json

Comment: no it's just a method

Comment: I could see you're not actually doing JWT authentication. It's just token authentication. If you want to do actual JWT authentication go through this tutorial.
https://thinkster.io/tutorials/django-json-api/authentication

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202420/discussion-between-aashay-amballi-and-kasia).